# Change the ratio of image output

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

One guy just told me about using the function `ggdraw` to overlap two figure.

When I saved the output using `ggsave`, the margin of both side (left, right) of my picture was shrank. I did use its arguments, but nothing happened.

Does anyone know about setting up the margin when using this function `ggdraw`?

**updated**

I would like to add the output that I got by using this code (it is a clip since I want you to see it clearly)

```
p1 <- cowplot::ggdraw(p) + cowplot::draw_plot(legend, x = .18, y = .25, width = 0.5, height = .5)

ggsave(plot = p1, filename = "outputs/tree_test.png",
         width = 45, height = 30, units = "cm", dpi = 300)
```

You guys can see that my margin of both sides has gone!.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ggsave` allows you to set the `width=` and `height=`, so you can control the ratio yourself.

Comment: yes, I did use `width` and `height` from `ggsave`, but it was still different between the picture with/without using `ggdraw` function

Comment: like the output I got, two margin of both sides, somehow, disappeared

Comment: Okay. It works for me, perhaps you should edit your question to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269) so that the rest of us can see what you're talking about. As it stands, this question is purely hypothetical without something concrete, typically a requirement or really-nice-to-have on StackOverflow.

Comment: yess thank you about this. I will edit now

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a `save_plot` function that is adapted for ggdraw objects. https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/drawing_with_on_plots.html

Comment: it would not work for me.